# Mapping inside apply in pandas/dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have some dataframe with temporal information per id, of around 30 periods for each person. 
The problem is that I have to calculate the net present value for some columns, aggregated by id. Even though it's a simple task, I have to repeat that for a lot of columns, and even for some new transformations.

The initial solution I've come with is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

    def npv(db, rate):
        count=1
        a=[]
        for i in db:
            a.append(i/(1+rate)**count)
            count+=1
        return sum(a)


    db=pd.read_csv("file_dir")
    group=db.groupby('id')
    npvs=group['column'].apply(lambda x: npv(x, 0.1))
```

Then I usually create a new column, where I insert the present value repeated each period for each person like this:

```
db['new_column']=db.id.map(lambda x: npvs[x])
```

just to keep with the original format (although it makes no sense).

With this, I have to repeat the operation for every column I want, instead of applying the function to a list of columns which could save me time.
I would like a solution more elegant, something that could map efficiently inside the apply. A solution might be apply `map` after `apply`, creating a column with the discounted factor for each period, and then to sum up the values. The problem is that I have to apply this solution for a lot of persons, with a file of around 40Gb that I cannot load into pandas.

I've tried with dask, but it doesn't allow iterating each group as in my function.

Any ideas for implementing this more elegantly on pandas, or how I could make a compatible solution with dask?

Comment: You can use `.agg` to apply a function over select columns. Although I'm not sure how efficient it would be. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html

Comment: I'll look into that tomorrow. Hope I can implement it on dask. Thanks!